# i18n how translate text in javascript

Tags: javascript, internationalization, translate

i try translate some text in javascript script. I have:

```
i18n: {
  messages: {
    en: {
      i18n_profile_alert:'Please draw a geometry with the Geometry selection',
    },
    de: {
      i18n_profile_alert:'Bitte zeichnen Sie mit der Geometry Auswahl eine Geometry',
    },
  },
},
```

in HTML i can get my translate message like this:

```
<span>{{$t('i18n_profile_alert')}}</span>
```

but in javascript it not working:

```
entegetGeometry() {
    const drawingUtil = vcs.vcm.util.Drawing.getInstance();
    const drawingId = this.$refs.geometrySelection.getDrawingId();
    if (!drawingId) {
      this.notifyError({{$t('i18n_profile_alert')}});
      return;
    }
```

How can I refer to my message in the javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with angular and you have created your project using Angular CLI, then you can use this package. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate

Using ng2-translate you can use multiple languages translation in your project.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but I use it in Vue.js project.